# Contiuous label error when fitting logistic regression model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am attempting a logistic regression model but getting an error. My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
Mileage_train, Mileage_test, Price_train, Price_test = train_test_split(Mileage, Price, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0 )
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
Mileage_train = sc.fit_transform(Mileage_train)
Mileage_test = sc.fit_transform(Mileage_test)

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
Mileage, price = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

classifier.fit(Mileage_train, Price_train)
```

The `ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'` error arises in the fit command:

[image: Value error]

Comment: Where is line #183?  I need to see snippet for continuous

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error says, `Unknown label type: 'continuous'` because you passed continuous numerical data as the target. But [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) is a **classification** algorithm (despite its name!). So it needs a discrete, categorical target.

Maybe you want to use a **regression** algorithm? Such as [linear regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).